# Password less ssh between two Amazon ec2 instances

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I have to install an 12.2 instance for that we need a password less *SSH* connection between 2 applications nodes. I created the instance using a private key called *EC2_linux*. I am able ssh to another *ec2 instance* as **ec2-user** but I want to connect as user *appltest*. I tried the following process but it is not working.

```
1. Server1: ssh-keygen -t rsa
2. Server1: copied the id_rsa.pub to server2 
3. server2: cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized-keys
```

But I am unable to *SSH* to the *server2* as **"ssh appltest@server2"** without password. How to achieve this setup?

Comment: Make sure these steps are performed by user appltest and not ec2-user

Comment: Hi Ajit, I have done these steps as appltest user only.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.